# fieldtype tag pairs doens't work

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have set up my own fieldtype. Then in the template I do this

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="1"}
    {myfield}tag {ttt} contetnt{/myfield}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

but it doesn't parse `myfield`. But if I do

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="1"}
    {myfield}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

A PHP

```
function replace_tag($data, $params = array(), $tagdata = FALSE)
{
    $vars= array('ttt' => 'test');
    $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($tagdata, array($vars));

    return $tagdata;
}
```

All is fine. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your fieldtype to act as a tag pair as well as a single tag you must add the following as a class variable:

```
$has_array_data = TRUE
```